# how to download the opengl documentation for offline reference?

Tags: opengl, documentation, offline

I need to take an emergency flight in a couple of hours and I need to develop while on the flight.

Is there a way to access the opengl documentation offline? A pdf or a set of html files that I can download?

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages/tree/master/gl4/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenGL reference pages GitHub repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages) has the HTML files (the result of DocBook conversion) embedded within them. Clone or download that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compact [quick-reference-card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl45-quick-reference-card.pdf) from `khronos.org` or the [core profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) both in `.pdf` format.

Answer (score -1):

[Zealdocs](https://zealdocs.org/) provides quite a few offline documentatons.